# Is 'But' an introductory word?

Tags: punctuation

I learnt that there should be a comma after an introductory word. For example,

> Meanwhile, we were planning our vacation.

Can 'But' be considered an introductory word? Is the following sentence punctuated correctly?

> But, I tried my best to pass the test.

Comment: In the sentence above, do you think there should be a comma after 'But'?

Comment: This is tricky. While I'd never use a comma after an introductory _Yet_, they're too commonly used (especially in the US) to be dismissed summarily as 'incorrect'. // If I wanted to convey a pause in speaking (for reflection?) say, I'd stick to more heavy-duty punctuation. "But ... wouldn't that contravene a Gricean Maxim?"

Comment: [In English, the rule is that you must separate words that aren’t part of the sentence but instead comment on the meaning of the sentence. Put another way, introductory words that appear at the beginning of a sentence are set off from what follows by commas.](https://www.dummies.com/education/language-arts/grammar/how-to-use-commas-with-introductory-words-and-phrases/) But that seems to me an incredibly strong prescriptive position. Having said that, I would never consider putting a comma after the first word of my preceding sentence here.

Comment: @FF Who's Geraldine Woods?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth, FumbleFingers Oh dear, I am even more confused now... hahahaha

Comment: @EdwinAshworth, OK.. So, _but_ is a conjunction, and we should not use commas after a conjunction. Does that sound correct?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: [English Grammar for Dummies, UK Edition Paperback – 23 Mar. 2007](https://www.amazon.co.uk/English-Grammar-Dummies-Lesley-Ward/dp/0470057521/ref=asc_df_0470057521/?tag=googshopuk-21&linkCode=df0&hvadid=310977525294&hvpos=&hvnetw=g&hvrand=7795231740653741839&hvpone=&hvptwo=&hvqmt=&hvdev=c&hvdvcmdl=&hvlocint=&hvlocphy=1006661&hvtargid=pla-458541699771&psc=1&th=1&psc=1) by Geraldine Woods (Author), Lesley J. Ward  (Author). But I think her position is OTT, as pointed  out before. To me, the *only* relevant rule here is *If you'd pause in speech, include a comma, **else don't***.

Comment: @FF You know I'm all for flexible comma usage, usually in line with pause indication. But there needs to be some degree of standardisation; not all ways of speaking are  clear or even acceptable. And speech can have idiosyncratic pauses. As I say, I'd signal a pause here with an ellipsis say, but we're entering style choices now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, no comma is needed. Countless examples can be found showing no comma use.

([ref. 1, 1997](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/But_is_it_True/Bg2f9CyXwscC?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22but%22&pg=PA431&printsec=frontcover)) But is this true ? Is human health conserved by mandating ever - lower exposures ?

([ref. 2, 2014](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/I_Know_God_Can_but_Will_He_Do_It_for_Me/sttaBAAAQBAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22but%22&pg=PT3&printsec=frontcover))But Will He Heal My Broken Heart?

([ref. 3, 2003](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/But_I_Want_a_Casserole/XH55FAccUNMC?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22but%22&pg=PA63&printsec=frontcover)) But I learned this weekend ~ it's not my life people would benefit from, rather God's work in my life.

([ref. 4, 2013](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Nothing_But_Trouble/kp5iBAAAQBAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22but%22&pg=PT46&printsec=frontcover)) But she really couldn't accuse him of more meaningless sweet-talk, because he had no way of knowing about all that.

([ref. 5](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Everything_but_the_Brain/Y0GlDQAAQBAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22but%22&pg=PP5&printsec=frontcover)) But just imagine, what if that could be the solution for someone who was watching their loved one aging and dying before his eyes.

If you go through the whole [page](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22but%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en) from which those references are taken, you will find that the use of the comma is exceptional.

([ref.](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/High_Yellow_but_a_Black_Woman_Forever_Mo/tmX2xtfrgqQC?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22but%22&pg=PA131&printsec=frontcover)) But, spiritual clothing, as you already know, must be worn one on top of the other.

It can be necessary sometimes when it is necessary from the point of view of syntax.

- But for two pictures that weren't framed the whole set had now new golden frames. (*except for…*)
- But, for two pictures nothing could be done, no restauration was possible. (*however …*)

Comment: Thank you so much :)

Comment: Yes, but why don't you state why a comma is not required.

Comment: @BillJ I wish I knew a principle that justifies that. I can speculate that the situation is different from that found for sentence adjuncts in initial position, as the conjunction would connect to what follows immediately, but  it's merely an idea of mine and at that not very enlightening in the way of providing a cause and effect explanation.

Comment: "But" belongs to several categories: adverb, noun and coordinator. In the latter use (as in the OP's example) it is part of the the coordinate that it introduces, i.e. it forms a constituent with the coordinate following it. Thus, syntactically it's not needed, though it is still found.

Comment: @BillJ That is putting flesh on the skeleton of a reason that I could muster up.